# Normalization of an 1:1 or 1:0 relationship

Tags: database, relational-database, normalization, 3nf

when using relation databases and you want 3NF (do you call it 3NF in english?), then you pull 1:1 relationsships together into one table. But what happens if the rationship is 1:0/1 (/ meaning or)?

Then you keep them separated to avoid blank spaces in tables? Kepping them apart is valid 3NF in ths case?

Comment: Wikipedia confirms it is caled 3NF in English :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 4):

Based on your question and subsequent comments on @paxdialbo's answer my understanding is you want a solution for storing optional attributes, of which there are many, while avoiding NULLs. Two ways of accomplishing this, [6th Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_normal_form) (6NF) or an [Entity Attribute Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) (EAV) model.

## 6th Normal Form

This involves creating a table specific to the attribute:

```
create table attributeName (
    id
    value
)
```

Where `id` is a foreign key and `value` captures that attribute (e.g. social security number). Absence of a record for a given key indicates non-existence.

## Entity Attribute Value

Now as you can imagine, 6th Normal Form can lead to table proliferation. An EAV model solves by using similar model for multiple attributes as such:

```
create table integerAttribute (
    name
    id
    value
)
```

The `name` column identifies the attribute (e.g. 'SocialSecurity'), albeit a more sophisticated implementation is instead of a `name` column, `name` is stored in a separate meta data table and referenced via a foreign key. Regardless, this approach implies have other tables for different data types (i.e. `datetimeAttribute`, `varcharAttribute`, etc...).

## Conclusion

The real question to ponder is how many optional attributes you're dealing with. If relatively few, the easiest solution is actually adding optional NULLable columns on the main table. 6NF and EAV add significant complexity and performance concerns. Often what's done when using one of these approaches is serializing the overall entity into a CLOB on the main table to simplify the common read (i.e. by primary key), to avoid multiple LEFT joins to retrieve a fully hydrated entity.

Comment: 3NF, BCNF, 5NF all require tables without nulls because all of them are defined for *relations* with values (not nulls). There is absolutely no need to apply 6NF just to avoid nulls and in most cases it probably isn't the best approach. I would recommend BCNF / 5NF as the default approach. Just create new tables for the columns that otherwise might have been nullable so that you don't have to put null markers or other placeholders in the places where no data exists.

Comment: At least, using multiple NULL is not an option is there exist some kind of relation between these attributes, like if one is NULL, then all the others must be NULL too. This is one would be an unambiguous case indicating a separate entity in a separate table should be used.

Answer (score 3):

Third normal form basically means that an attribute (or column) depends on the key, the whole key and nothing but the key (so help me, Codd).

If you have an attribute which is either there or not there, that attribute itself may still follow the rules.

In those cases, I would simply keep the attributes in the main table and make them nullable to indicate whether or not they're appropriate for the row.

By way of (contrived) example, you may have a `SocialSecurityNumber` attribute as your primary key (I won't go into the arguments as to whether this is a good idea here or whether you should use a surrogate key since it's irrelevant to the question).

Further assume that you have a distinct `BankAccount` attribute for paying their wage into, and that you're not one of those nice employers that can distribute a wage to multiple bank accounts for the purpose of dodging taxes :-)

Now the bank account of someone *is* dependent entirely on the chosen key but not everyone may possess one (they may be paid in cash). In other words, a classic `1:0/1` case as you put it.

In that case, you would simply make the bank account number nullable in the table.

Comment: What if their are a lot of extra attributes, so having it all in one table makes the table very sparse and some attributes don't make any sense for the entry. Maybe a good way to imagin it would be thing of an IS A relationship. E.g. HUMAN gets identified with the SOCIAL_SEC_NUMBER. But now you nerver get a pure HUMAN but only children of HUMAN, e.g. GOD,DICTATOR,OLIMPIC_SPORTS_PERSON. Now having a Attribute TESTED_POSITIV_FOR_DOPING doens't make seens for GOD. Does it not make more seens only keeping the subset of attributes that every child can supply in the HUMAN table?

Comment: 3NF is not for saving space - that's a usual consequence but that's not its raison d'etre. And, if your `IsDrugFiend` column only applies to sports people, it's no longer dependent on all-and-nothing-but-the-key since it now depends on the person-type as well. So that model is flawed.

Comment: Okay I thing it all will turns around the same point that there is no "IS A"-relationship in a relational database. Is 3NF not possible in such an scenario?  If I split the IsDrugFriend into a new table and put the SOCIAL_SEC_NUM as a key, then it only depends on the key? The dependance on the TYPE_OF_HUMAN is sort of implicit... Having it all in one table if wrong, having it in more than one table is wrong as well... :-( What shall I do?

Comment: “In that case, you would simply make the bank account number nullable in the table”: alternatively, especially if it implies multiple columns, an idea may be to have a second table, with no entry when the property does not exists and an entry when the property exists. I'm just not sure about what normalization says about it, neither if it says something on this. This is a 1 to 0‑1 relation handled like a 1 to many relation. May be the one to many relation is more generally a one to unknown‑cardinal relation, a case in which the 1 to 0‑1 would fall too?

Answer (score 2):

Building on your comments with paxdiablo . . .

Let's look at some SQL. I could have chosen better names for the columns, but I deliberately didn't. I wasn't being lazy; I had good reasons. An external predicate is how users are supposed to interpret the contents of a table.

```
-- External predicate: Human is identified by 
--                         Social Security Account Number [ssan] 
--                     and has full name [full_name] 
--                     and result of last HIV test [hiv_status]
--                     and has checking account [bank_account]
--                     and was born at exactly [birth_date].
--
create table human (
ssan char(9) primary key, 
full_name varchar(35) not null,
hiv_status char(3) not null default 'Unk' 
    CHECK (hiv_status in ('Unk', 'Pos', 'Neg')),
bank_account varchar(20),
birth_date timestamp not null
);

-- External predicate: Human athlete identified by 
--                         Social Security Account Number [ssan] 
--                     has current doping status [doping_status]
create table athlete (
ssan char(9) not null primary key references human (ssan),
doping_status char(3) not null default 'Unk' 
    CHECK (doping_status in ('Unk', 'Pos', 'Neg'))
);

-- External predicate: Human dictator identified by 
--                         Social Security Account Number [ssan] 
--                     has estimated benevolence of [benevolence_score].
create table dictator (
ssan char(9) not null primary key references human (ssan),
benevolence_score integer not null default 3 
    CHECK (benevolence_score between 1 and 5) -- 1 is least, 5 is most benevolent
);
```

All three of those tables are in 5NF. (Which means they're also in 3NF.)

You said

> there is no "IS A"-relationship in a
>   relational database

An athlete "IS A" human, because its identifier is a human identifier. In this case, its primary key is a foreign key that `references human (ssan)`.  Database designers don't usually talk in terms of "IS A" and "HAS A" relationships, because predicates are more precise and expressive. You can see the difference by comparing these two statements.

- human "HAS A" [birth_date]
- human was born at exactly
  [birth_date]

That last one is deliberately a little jarring. I defined the birth_date column as a timestamp--it accommodates both date and time. It illustrates how external predicates are to some extent independent of the column names. (It also illustrates how the loose coupling between predicates and column names might not be such a good idea here.)

You said

> But now you nerver get a pure HUMAN
>   but only children of HUMAN

I'm not sure what you mean by "pure human". You can get all the humans by simply

```
SELECT * FROM human;
```

If you mean that you can't have a human unless the human is an athlete or dictator (or whatever), then you're mistaken. If there's no row in athlete for a specific SSAN, then the human identified by that SSAN isn't an athlete. If there's no row in dictator for a specific SSAN, then the human identified by that SSAN isn't a dictator.